# Laravel Auth returning false

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am working with Laravels built in `Auth::attempt` feature to try and create a login script for my website. However, `Auth::attempt` always returns false. This question appears to be similar to many others having a similar issue, however the answers that they received did not help / apply to my issue. I am following a tutorial on Phpacademy on YouTube, and my login is almost verbatim. Did Laravel modify the way `Auth::attempt` now works? Any help would be appreciated. Below is my login function in my AccountController.php

```
public function postLogin() {

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'    
        )
    );

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('account-login')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
    }

    else {

        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'active' => 1
        ));

        if($auth) {
            Redirect::intended('/');
        }

        else {
            return Redirect::route('account-login')
                        ->with('global',"Email/password wrong");
        }

    }

    return Redirect::route('account-login')
                        ->with('global',"There was a problem signing you in.");
}
```

models/User.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    //fillable for the database
    protected $fillable = array('email','password','first-name','last-name','username','city','state','password','password_temp','code','active');

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    }

?>
```

Comment: Yes I think Laravel has changed some security settings since that phpacademy tutorial was made. From memory, it was just a simple little thing that was related to CSRF protection or something.
Can you post your code for this file please:  `app/models/User.php`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it affects you, because you dont seem to be using "remember me" feature, but Laravel introduced the following security feature at version 4.1.2.
Here is an explanation of the issues/fix many of us needed to run to get auth working after following the phpacademy auth tutorial.
Hopefully it helps.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26